# How to simplify a leading-NA count function, and generalize it to work on matrix, dataframe

Tags: r, vectorization, logical-operators, na

I wrote a leading-NA count function, it works on vectors. However:

a) Can you simplify my version?

b) Can you also generalize it to work directly on matrix, dataframe (must still work on individual vector), so I don't need `apply()`? Try to avoid all `*apply` functions, fully vectorize, it must still work on a vector, and no special-casing if at all possible.

```
leading_NA_count <- function(x) { max(cumsum((1:length(x)) == cumsum(is.na(x)))) }
# v0.1: works but seems clunky, slow and unlikely to be generalizable to two-dimensional objects

leading_NA_count <- function(x) { max(which(1:(length(x)) == cumsum(is.na(x))), 0) }
# v0.2: maybe simpler, needs max(...,0) to avoid max failing with -Inf if the which(...) is empty/ no leading-NAs case: e.g. c(1,2,3) 

# (Seems impossible to figure out how to use which.max/which.min on this)


leading_NA_count <- function(x) { max(cumsum((1:length(x)) == cumsum(is.na(x)))) }
set.seed(1234)
mm <- matrix(sample(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,2), 6*5, replace=T), nrow=6,ncol=5)
mm
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA    2   NA    1
[3,]   NA    0   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA    1   NA    2
[5,]    1    0   NA   NA    1
[6,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA

leading_NA_count(mm)
[1] 4 # WRONG, obviously (looks like it tried to operate on the entire matrix by-column or by-row)
apply(mm,1,leading_NA_count)
[1] 5 2 1 2 0 0 # RIGHT
```

Comment: you could just have your function identify the structure of the input and have it act differently for matrices and vectors

Comment: @rawr: a) in any case I want it vectorized, for performance b) already considered that, but this seems simple enough we should be able to do without special-casing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works whether `mm` is a `matrix`, `vector` or `data.frame`.  See `?max.col` for more info:

```
max.col(cbind(!is.na(rbind(NA, mm)), TRUE), ties = "first")[-1] - 1
```

Comment: Brilliant! `cbind(..., TRUE)` and `rbind(NA, ...)` are just adding a dummy column and row to coerce vector to 2D object; we then remove the corresponding dummy components in the result with the `[-1]` and `- 1`, right?

Comment: Yes, the `rbind` of the `NA` forces it to be 2D and and the `cbind` takes care of the case that the row is entirely `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a) of your question this is the simplest function I could think of:

```
leadingNaCount = function(x) { sum(cumprod(is.na(x))) }
```

Comment: Ok now b) do it without needing `apply`. `cumprod` does not vectorize.

Comment: @smci Yes it does.  The first three words in the description of `?cumprod` are "Returns a vector".  I think we're not on the same page as far as what defines "vectorizing."

Comment: cumprod does not handle 2D objects, then.