# Remove leading and trailing NA

Tags: r, subset, na, missing-data

I need to delete *leading* and *trailing* missing values (`NA`) from a vector. `NA`s between numbers should be kept. Note that my next step is index another vector without `NA` and keep only values with the same position as in first vector. Here is the example:

```
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5,2,3,1,2,1,5,2, NA, NA, 2,3,2,NA,NA,NA)
b <- sample(1:21)
```

My desired output is:

```
a1 <- c(5,2,3,1,2,1,5,2,NA,NA,2,3,2)
# leading and trailing NAs removed

b1 <- b[6:18]
# subset with the indices kept in "a" above.
```

I thing I can do this with come conditional loop but I want to vectorize it. Thx for help!

Comment: [this to count NAs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752617/how-to-simplify-a-leading-na-count-function-and-generalize-it-to-work-on-matrix), and [this to trim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639599/remove-leading-nas-to-align-data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for the first and the last non-NA value and keep that part of the vector:

```
a1 <- a[min(which(!is.na(a))):max(which(!is.na(a)))]

> a1
[1]  5  2  3  1  2  1  5  2 NA NA  2  3  2
```

Comment: This solution is clear, but how will the OP do his next step after that? Maybe you should edit to something like: `p <- which(!is.na(a)) ; a1 <- a[p[1]:p[length(p)]] ; b1 <- b[p[1]:p[length(p)]]`?

Answer (score 5):

```
keep <- !cumprod(is.na(a)) & rev(!cumprod(is.na(rev(a))))
a[keep]
#[1]  5  2  3  1  2  1  5  2 NA NA  2  3  2
b[Keep]
```

`is.na` returns `TRUE` for `NA` values. The `cumprod` function coerces the logical values to integers and returns `1` for the leading `NA`s and `0` for all other values. `!` (negation) coerces the integer values to logical values again. We then use `rev` for the trailing `NA`s.

Answer (score 5):

Using zoo package:

```
library(zoo)

na.trim(a)
```

> **Description**
>
> Generic function for removing leading and trailing NAs.