# How to remove a tail with NA in r?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a vector:

```
a <- c(NA,1:5,NA,NA,1:3, rep(NA,round(runif(1,0,100))))
```

I need to remove the trailing `NA`s. Desired result:

```
c(NA, 1:5, NA, NA, 1:3)
```

Comment: Related: [Remove leading and trailing NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759027/remove-leading-and-trailing-na)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
a[1:max(which(!is.na(a)))]
# [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  1  2  3
```

We subset the vector from position 1 to the last non NA value.

Comment: This one fails in the (probably very unlikely) case when `a` contains only `NA`.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be

```
a[rev(cumprod(rev(is.na(a)))) == 0]
# [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  1  2  3
```

Here are the steps:

```
(a <- c(NA, 1:5, NA, NA, 1:3, NA, NA))
# [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  1  2  3 NA NA
is.na(a)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
rev(is.na(a))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
cumprod(rev(is.na(a)))
# [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
rev(cumprod(rev(is.na(a))))
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the maximum position which is not an NA and subset accordingly

```
> a[1:max(which(!is.na(a)))]
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Also a possibility:

```
a[cumsum(!is.na(a)) != max(cumsum(!is.na(a))) * is.na(a)]

 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  1  2  3
```

In idividual steps:

```
is.na(a)

 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

cumsum(!is.na(a))

 [1] 0 1 2 3 4

cumsum(!is.na(a)) != max(cumsum(!is.na(a)))

 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

cumsum(!is.na(a)) != max(cumsum(!is.na(a))) * is.na(a)

 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Just for fun, a little benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)

a <- rep(a, 1e5)

 microbenchmark(
 markus = a[1:max(which(!is.na(a)))],
 Julius_Vainora = a[rev(cumprod(rev(is.na(a)))) == 0],
 Kim = rm_NA_tail(a),
 tmfmnk = a[cumsum(!is.na(a)) != max(cumsum(!is.na(a))) * is.na(a)],
 nsinghs = a[1:(length(a) - rle(is.na(rev(a)))$lengths[1])],
 times = 5
)

Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
         markus 150.7346 153.0674 156.4194 153.3031 159.4718  165.5201     5 a  
 Julius_Vainora 393.8520 418.8186 616.3269 703.4022 749.6600  815.9018     5  bc
            Kim 370.7680 382.1826 536.0828 632.0031 642.1882  653.2720     5  bc
         tmfmnk 390.2626 415.2378 466.4245 415.8310 423.3828  687.4082     5  b 
        nsinghs 537.0404 781.1403 798.6929 793.1027 842.6777 1039.5033     5   c
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
rm_NA_tail <- function(a) {
  if (is.na(a[length(a)])) {
    return(a[is.na(match(data.table::rleid(a), max(data.table::rleid(a))))])
  } else {
    return(a)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `rle()`

```
a[1:(length(a) - rle(is.na(rev(a)))$lengths[1])]
#  [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  1  2  3
```

`rle(is.na(rev(a)))$lengths[1]` gets the count of trailing `NA` in the vector, then subtract it from the total vector `length` to get the index up to which you want to keep the vector.